# Spring MVC4 + Thymeleaf Form data to Controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring MVC4 application that uses Thymeleaf as a templating engine. I have a table with team member information that has an embedded form in each row with a **delete** button to allow deleting a user by row. below is the table section and a screenshot of what it currently looks like...

```
<table class="bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id">Name</th>
            <th data-field="name">Password</th>
            <th data-field="price">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
            <td th:text="${user.userName}">Name</td>
            <td th:text="${user.password}">Password</td>
            <td th:text="${user.email}">Email</td>
            <td>
                <!-- Submit the user to be deleted -->
                <form th:object="${user}" class="col s12" action="/deleteUser" method="post">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light red col" type="submit" name="deleteUser">
                    Delete
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

When I click the **delete** button my **TeamController** picks up the request but all the instance variables are null, I'm fairly new to Spring MVC4 and Thymeleaf so not sure if this is a valid approach or not? I am assuming that the object in the form is a reference to the user object in the row so not sure why its coming null on the controller side?

**Note:** the user object I am passing in the form is an instance of UserAccount.java that lives in the Model.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it with below updates to my form...

```
<td>
<!-- Submit the user to be deleted -->
<form th:object="${UserAccount}" class="col s12" th:action="@{/deleteUser}" method="post">
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light red col" type="submit" name="deleteUser">Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="userName" name="userName" th:value="${user.userName}" />
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```